# I am Using Command Line Data Loader using Cliq, having error

Tags: data-loader

I am upserting a CSV in sandbox using command line data loader with the help of Cliq, I am trying to upsert Account object and using a custom external Id field but after executing batch file I am having some error...

> ERROR [UpsertCSV] client.PartnerClient runOperation (Par
>   tnerClient.java:332) - Error while calling web service operation:
>   describeSObjec t, error was: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting
>   element 'urn:partner.soap .sforce.com:queryable' but found
>   'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:namedLayoutInfos'
>   com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Unexpected element. Parser was
>   expecting elem ent 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:queryable' but found
>   'urn:partner.soap.sforce.c om:namedLayoutInfos'
>           at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.verifyTag(TypeMapper.java:387)
>           at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.verifyElement(TypeMapper.java:416)
>           at com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeSObjectResult.loadFields(DescribeSObj
>   ectResult.java:822)
>           at com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeSObjectResult.load(DescribeSObjectRes
>   ult.java:743)
>           at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:629)
>           at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:505)
>           at com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeSObjectResponse_element.loadFields(De
>   scribeSObjectResponse_element.java:62).

Please Suggest if you have any solution. Thanks...